# How to draw downhill path with TileMill and KML?

Tags: kml, style, line, tilemill

I have a kml file which contains downhill paths and other points. Here is an [example](http://www.skimap.org/data/1006/osm/kml/2011-12-28.kml).

I imported the file to TileMill and I used Save & Style, but nothing appeared except a few points. I think the points are from the beginning of the file:

```
<Placemark id="">
          <name>Ospizo del San Gottardo</name>
          <styleUrl>#style-Hotel</styleUrl>
          <Point>
            <coordinates>8.5678973,46.5553576,0</coordinates>
          </Point>
</Placemark>
```

However, I have to show lines too, and I do not know why they do not appear.

```
<Placemark id="w30923462">
            <description>, Downhill Run Difficulty: Intermediate</description>
            <styleUrl>#style-Ski_Run_Downhill_Intermediate</styleUrl>
            <LineString>
              <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
              <coordinates>8.6117521,46.6026559,0 8.611656,46.6027044,0 8.6111908,46.602598,0 8.6107463,46.6024283,0 8.6107241,46.6022232,0 8.6107654,46.6019631,0 8.6107568,46.6018982,0 8.610671,46.6017508,0 8.6102676,46.6015562,0 8.6098813,46.6015739,0 8.6095809,46.6017036,0 8.6090574,46.6021223,0 8.6087655,46.6022462,0 8.6085767,46.6022992,0 8.6084051,46.6020987,0 8.6082248,46.6017508,0 8.6081304,46.6011611,0 8.6080875,46.6009134,0 8.6078042,46.6005301,0 8.6071605,46.6004357,0 8.6070318,46.6003945,0 8.6065511,46.6002057,0 8.606328,46.5998991,0 8.6058387,46.5995158,0 8.6050662,46.5992563,0 8.6042165,46.5986724,0 8.6036243,46.5982891,0 8.6030492,46.5997634,0 8.6032618,46.6009642,0 8.6028184,46.6036218,0 8.6021304,46.6050714,0 8.602161,46.6064789,0 8.6024209,46.6072562,0 8.6022986,46.6078444,0 8.6016411,46.6090943,0 8.600525,46.6091468,0 8.6004027,46.6093674,0 8.6009378,46.6096194,0 8.6010754,46.609924,0 8.6006168,46.6101341,0 8.5993019,46.6109533,0 8.5989961,46.6117095,0 8.5986292,46.6130434,0 8.5983234,46.6139781,0 8.5975131,46.6145032,0 8.5969168,46.6155219,0 8.5971767,46.6164251,0 8.5969627,46.6166981,0 8.5969412,46.617104,0 8.5969321,46.6172757,0 8.5959077,46.6183664,0</coordinates>
            </LineString>
          </Placemark>
```

Can anyone explain why the lines are missing for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attached kml has more than one geometry type in this case Points & Polylines.

So i would recommend you to use gdal library to convert kml to shapefile that will save each layer as separate shape-file and than you load them in Tilemill. you can do the same using QGIS. I hope it will help.

**GDAL Command for conversion from kml to shp:**

ogr2ogr -f 'Esri Shapefile' output_file/ input_file.kml

Comment: I will try GDAL, but at now I just deleted the Points. Thank you for your answer.